# Should I use response.send() in 'finally' block when writing Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions

Im' trying to understand using promises with Google Cloud Functions a bit better. I just learned about the 'finally' method on promises, which is called after all promises in the chain are fully resolved or rejected. In a http function is it good practice to put response.send() inside of the finally method?

The below code uses request-promise-native for the http request. In the first .then() I call parseSchedule, which uses the cheerio web scraping api to loop through some data and on a website, and add it to the scheduledGames array (synchronously, I think).

I return from that and the then log that data to the console in writeDB, but one thing I noticed is that I see response.send() log 'execution finished' before I see the data from scheduleGames in the log. Is that correct?

Should I be using the 'finally' block like this?
Thanks,

```
    const options = {
        uri: 'https://www.cbssports.com/nba/schedule/' + urlDate,
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    return request(options)
    .then(parseSchedule)
    .then(writeSchedule)
    .catch((err) => console.log("there was an error: " + err))
    .finally(res.send("execution finished"));

    function parseSchedule($){

          const scheduledGames = [];

            $('tbody').children('tr').each((i, element) => {

                const gameTime = $(element).children('td').eq(2).find('a').text()
                const scheduledGame = { gameTime: gameTime};

                scheduledGames.push(scheduledGame);

        });

        return scheduledGames;
   }

    function writeDB(scheduledGames){
        console.log(scheduledGames);     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It typically makes more sense to send a success response at the time in the promise chain when everything is successful, or send an error response in a catch handler. If you do these two things, it doesn't make sense to use finally at all, since success and error are the only two cases you really need to handle.  Unless you have some special case, stick to just success and error.

Comment: To add to what Doug just stated, finally block can be used to log, close any streams, do some cleanup at the end. But apart from that in your use case, success and error scenarios should suffice!

Comment: Thank you both, I get now why its unnecessary to use .finally like that, and how .finally should be used instead, but still don't understand why in theory it wouldn't (and in my case didn't) work. Doesn't .finally() get called last?

Comment: It's not possible to say for sure without seeing the entire code of your function (you've shown just a bit of it here).

Comment: One problem with finally is the lack of variables being created inside try is not available. So you have to make things outside try, and if you want to catch any errors on that code, it will not work. I use finally today to close of a database connection f.ex. Just like LearningEveryday mentions, close streams. 

Hope you found a good solution @LouisSankey